# Mount remote directory of server with no direct route but having an intermediate server that only receives ssh connections

Tags: linux, ssh, sshfs, bsd

The setup I'm facing is this one:

In server A I'd like to mount a directory (let's call it `SHARED`) from server B.
There is no route and no way to add any from A to B or from B to A.
The inverse, to mount a directory from A in B is also necessary.

There is a third server C.  C can ping A and B, but cannot `ssh` to any of them.
But A and B can `ssh` to C.  C cannot NFS (or Samba) export directories.

This [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/616182/how-to-mount-local-directory-to-remote-like-sshfs#answer-1567643) comes close to it, but it's lacking the second branch of it the common share of a directory.

It mounting a directory of A in B (or vice-versa) is not possible, is there a way to mount a directory in C that is shared both for A and B, like if C was exported as a NFS share, but using `sshfs` in reverse mode?

Answer (score 0):

#### `sshfs`

> A and B can `ssh` to C.

> is there a way to mount a directory in C that is shared both for A and B, like if C was exported as a NFS share, but using `sshfs` in reverse mode?

I don't know what you mean by "reverse mode", but since you can `ssh` from A to C, you should be able to run `sshfs` on A to mount a directory existing on C (unless the SSH server on C does not support SFTP). It's quite straightforward:

```
# on A
sshfs user@C:/specific/dir/of/C /some/mountpoint
```

The same for B. This way A will see `/specific/dir/of/C` as `/some/mountpoint` on A; and B will see `/specific/dir/of/C` as `/some/mountpoint` on B.

Disadvantages:

- Whatever A (or B) does to its `/some/mountpoint`, on C it will be done by `user`. `sshfs` on A (or B) uses FUSE and [there is a way to allow users other than the invoker to use it on A (or B)](https://superuser.com/a/1758136/432690), still on C they all will act as `user`.
- Additional problems may arise if `user` specified by A is different than `user` specified by B and the two users cannot find a "common" directory on C that fits them in terms of ownership and permissions.
- Copying a file from A to B (or from B to A) requires uploading it from A (B) to C and then downloading from C to B (A). You cannot do this by acting on A xor B alone.
- Also such copying requires you to download not too fast (or not too soon), so when you reach the end of a file, it's the real end, not because you caught up to the uploading process that runs in the same time and is going to keep appending to the file existing on C. In practice you would most likely want one end to upload fully before the other end downloads (or uses) the file. While copying a directory, the downloader would most likely want to wait for the uploader to upload the whole directory, otherwise it could miss some files.

---

#### Chaining tunnels

From A you can reach a TCP port of B by chaining two SSH tunnels. In [this another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/753160/108618) I do this by working from a "middle node", because in that case there is SSH access from the middle to each end. You need to do this by working from both ends towards the "middle node" (which is your C) because these are the directions you can `ssh` in. Proceed like this:

```
# on A
ssh -N -L 3333:localhost:4444 user@C
```

```
# on B
ssh -N -R 4444:localhost:5555 user@C
```

When these work, any process on A that connects to `localhost:3333` will be tunneled to `localhost:4444` on C, ultimately to `localhost:5555` on B.

`3333` and `4444` are arbitrary ports, adjust the numbers to your needs (mind [privileged ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16564/108618)). `5555` is the port on B used by the service you want to reach.

Notes:

- The situation is symmetrical, so to reach a service of A from B, just swap A and B in the above example.
- Some services require more than one port.
- You can use more than one `-L` and/or `-R` option with a single `ssh` invocation. This means you can establish many chained tunnels (some in one direction, some in the opposite direction) using just one `ssh` on A and one `ssh` on B.
- `~/.ssh/config` is your friend. On A and on B define the respective parts of the tunnels in the config file and then `ssh -N user@C` on each end will be enough. See `man 5 ssh_config`.
- `autossh` is also your friend.
- SSH cannot tunnel UDP. Do not trust contraptions like in [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/53109/432690), they are [flawed](https://superuser.com/q/53103/432690#comment344670_53109). In general [`ssh -w` can be used](https://superuser.com/a/53149/432690) but [it's hard](https://superuser.com/a/1752063/432690) even when you don't need to chain connections.